# model validation to disallow ability to update a specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so what I want to accomplish is to allow a user set a started_at date in the database. However I do not want them to be able to edit that at a later stage.

So the reason why I'm having this issue is that I have an ajax calls that goes off when you join a session, that sets created_at. Issue is if you refresh your browser that will be updated. However I'd like to avoid that. After that I have a heartbeat that checks for time spent.

So how do I allow them to initially set a started_at but disallow them to update started_at if it's present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this as a before_save hook in the model.

```
before_save do
  self.started_at = started_at_was if started_at_changed? && started_at_was.present?
end
```